# Remove from Master Activities Calendar (MAC) option

Tags: 2010, calendar

Using SharePoint 2010 -  I have 4 calendars all rolling up into a MAC. However, the ADMIN for the calendar is requiring a way for him to be able to disable the item from being shown on the MAC, but still showing on the original source calendar.

I know there is a way to do it - the last place I was at had this. It was a column on the content type (and newform.aspx form) that had a check box to either add or remove. I am just not sure how to code something like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In all the calendars that roll up into your master, you'd need to create a view that is filtered based on that checkbox being checked. Then you use those filtered views in your master.

No code necessary.